# LicenseCheckerCallback cannot be resolved into a type

Tags: android, android-lvl

I've just started playing around with Android Licensing and I ran into this problem.

I have created the library project and linked my application project to the library project. It was working fine for some time, but after I installed Google APIs package from the Android SDK and AVD Manager, my projects were rebuilt and I came across this error. Nothing in my code was changed whatsoever and I was just wondering if anyone knows what happened or how to fix it?

Thanks!

EDIT: When I chose the option "Fix project setup..." and "Add project 'licensing_proj' to build path", it adds the library project as a project in the build path and gives me this error when running the emulator: `Could not find licensing_proj.apk!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what happened but removing and adding the library as a new project worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, but after I removed all the same libiary referenced, and added the library in project properties->android page, and recompile, works.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html